# Limit of Attributes Stored In An HTTPSession

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, configuration, jakarta-ee

Is there an maximum amount of data that can be stored in a single session? I know that it is a bad deal to store lots of data just in the session. However, is there a limit to the amount that is stored, if so how is the application notified that this limit has been reached? Is there an exception just for this?

Context: I'm referring to Tomcat 6.0, wihtout being clustered, using the StandardManager (for Sessions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard about such a limit in Tomcat, behind the scenes it is just a map, so *the heap is the limit*, probably.

But if your session is so huge, you might consider synchronization on session, as modifying large objects might increase the risk of some race-conditions (accessing the session is not synchronized between different threads/request from the same user for performance reasons - you are making a choice, whether you can accept the risk or not).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tomcat ever passivates anything to disk in its default configuration, so everything you put in session will take space in memory. The limit is the heap size of the JVM running Tomcat.

If you put too many objects in session, you risk getting an OutOfMemoryError at some time.